# Communication between JSP, Servlet, DAO while working on database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc, dao

While learning about JSP, Servlets and DAO I've followed **[this](http://www.javasqlsecurity.com/2010/11/servlet-jdbc-dao-tutorial)** tutorial and hopefully learned a little bit about proper way of using JSP/Servlet to edit SQL Server table.

Anyway, I have:

- POJO.java
- DAO.java
- SERVLET.java
- PAGE.jsp

How do I implement another JSP page that displays data rows? Is it possible to make a JSP page that would call on DAO/Servlet for data extraction and then display the data on itself (JSP)?

When opening website, I'm calling Servlet and the process goes like: `Servlet -> DAO -> JSP`. Do I need another Servlet+JSP files or can I add just JSP file that would use current Servlet to populate the page?

My questions should probably go to the author of the tutorial but I'm hoping here for some suggestions from a different point of view.

Comment: Could you please elaborate _I'm calling Servlet: Servlet -> DAO -> JSP. How should I add a second site for user to simply browse the data? Another Servlet and another JSP file or can I add just JSP file that would use current Servlet?_

Comment: @JigarJoshi What I mean is this example is calling a Servlet that returns JSP page - this is like CMS. How do I add a front page for everyone without edit rights? Should it be another Servlet or can it be JSP that calls the same Servlet as CMS.

Comment: No same servlet will do the job, you resolve the role of current user and store it in session, check from session that if user has the role then enable view, also add this security at servlet/service

Comment: @JigarJoshi So, I make my Servlet decide what JSP to open depending on whether there's an active admin session or not? If session exists I keep returning my CMS.jsp, if no session then it goes to default.jsp

Comment: well if ther eis no big difference then you could do it in the same jsp, just show/hide features using condition check and also make it secure at servlet end

Comment: Why downvote? is it the link? Can't really explain problem very well without better knowledge of Java and can't correct it if I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: @JigarJoshi I'm asking in general. -1 doesn't help in getting answers. Thanks for your comments, I'll try to follow your suggestions and do it this way. Feel free to post an answer if you have some further advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, you already have almost everything you need in order to do what you want. The DAO has a method called list() that will query the db and return an arraylist of employee objects so you're good there. However, the servlet and the jsp page need to be altered in order to make it work but add the relevant code to the servlet to use the DAO to just get the list of employees.
Before the start of the try block add

```
ArrayList<employee> employeeList = null;
```

Add this code to the existing code in the process() method of the servlet.

```
else if (StringUtils.equals(actionContext, "list")) {
    employeeList = dao.list();
    request.setAttribute("employeeList", employeeList);
  }
```

The javascript on the jsp will have to be changed in order to facilitate this since the javascript is driving what is passed to the servlet and you would have to add a button to the jsp that would call the javascript function similar to this.

```
<input type='button' value='List Employees' onclick="submitForm('list')" />
```

That should point you in the right direction and allow you to still use the code from the tutorial with slight modifications. Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, I'll need a totally different JSP for the default user site. I can do that with `request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/default.jsp").forward(
        request, response);`, right? It is possible to add a login form somewhere on default.jsp that would switch user to editable "admin mode"?

Comment: The welome-file-list in the web.xml lists index.jsp as the welcome file so it should be displayed as the default jsp for the web app if you entered "http://localhost:8080/Example14/" instead of "http://localhost:8080/Example14/Servlet3" and you could add your login form there. When you enter "http://localhost:8080/Example14/Servlet3" into the address bar you are bypassing index.jsp and calling the servlet directly and the servlet is then redirecting you to employee_maintenance.jsp.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) However, what if I want this index.jsp to both display login form AND non-editable database records. How do I call servlet (to do the whole query processing) from index.jsp?

Comment: If your original question has been answered please mark it as answered and post another question asking about that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, I can sujest you to do the next:
1. Attach your data to the reguest (use request.setAttribute(Name,Object));
2. use jsp:import to connect next JSP page;
3. In those servlet, extract your data by request.getAttribute(Name), convert it to the type you need and use.

Howewer, I'm not sure if this will be correct enough - as I know, you'll not actually copy you're var, so this will not take much additional time or memory, but I can't be sure enough, if this is the most 'adequate' way to solve this...